# Data Privacy Laws in the US

Tags: privacy, data

I have found a website that likely has several hundred thousands of users where it's possible to look at the network traffic in order to see other users' personal information (email address, date of birth, full name, home address). I have reported this to the website using several different modes of communication but they still have not resolved the issue. I'm curious about a couple things:

- Is this breaking a law? I believe in the US we don't have super strict data privacy rules compared to Europe, but this seems like it's such detailed information that it shouldn't be legal.
- If it is breaking a law and the site is not fixing the issue, where should I report this issue to?

Comment: There might be state-level privacy laws that could apply, for example if the website collects the data of California consumers.

Comment: They definitely have users in California, but due to the nature of the "bug" that lets me see the data, I'm only able to see data for people that are near me.

Comment: Related https://iapp.org/resources/article/us-state-privacy-legislation-tracker/

Comment: The FTC has authority over online privacy policies, violations, and the like. Reporting what you've found to them is one step you can take. https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/topics/protecting-consumer-privacy-security

Comment: Thanks everyone